# Test a parameter from anonymous window

Tags: apex, pagereference, global-variables

I am debugging code where it gets parameters from an opportunity record page but it seems to return empty. How can I test this in an anonymous window: `productFamily = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('productFamily');`

Comment: I think writing a test class would be good in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with following code it work for your question
 opportunityPage is a visual page, Your controller related to which page

```
    PageReference pageRef = Page.opportunityPage;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('productFamily','Value to be passed');
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

First you have to set value to **productFamily** in test cases ,
Then try get run your code

```
productFamily = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('productFamily');
```

Comment: Test.setCurrentPage() can only be called from testMethods. This won't work in anonymous apex.